# Email not receiving Amazon SES and SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

Maybe someone knows what the problem is. I can't properly set up receiving emails on SES and sending them to SNS.

There is a domain, conventionally **@example.com**.

I set up the rules set (active), rule, MX on the mail server, everything fine if I check it on mxtoolbox.com.

| Pref | Hostname | IP Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | inbound-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com | 54.240.250.228 Amazon.com, Inc. (AS16509) |

If I send an email from **reply@example.com** to any mail, then everything comes and is loggen via SNS, and when I want to receive email in **reply@example.com**, nothing happens on SES and nothing logged in SNS.
Maybe someone came across this?

***Rule:**
Recipients (All recipients under verified domains)
Actions 1. SNS Action Write email to SNS topic 111 using Base64*

Comment: Does your SNS topic have any subscribers?

Comment: @jellycsc, Yes

40b4a89d-1f0c-4ad3-8a52-02eb24c8e4f2 https://1ed8157e1ba0.ngrok.io/api/v1/ses  Confirmed HTTPS

Comment: Did you have server-side encryption turned on? If so, could you try turning it off?

Comment: No. If I send a test message from SNS to the server, then it comes

Comment: @AndreyKalenyuk any news on this? I have a similar problem :/